# Curve/Wrap Text Within its Container with Rounded Borders? (CSS/React)

Tags: css, reactjs

My text isn't staying within the curved borders of its container, is there a way to fix this?

Emphasis on wrapping text to the inside of the container and not just fitting text. I'm not looking to hide the text with a scroll bar, the text should simply wrap to the inside of the container. Padding does not solve this issue, because padding is unidirectional and doesn't account for a text that wraps.

code: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-mclean-cuijl?file=/src/App.js:115-127

```js
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="appContainer">
        <p>lkajsdf alsdkj;las l;dsjlsd fljfaaklehfa elaksdfaslkdfaekh t</p>
        <p>lkajsdf alsdkj;las l;dsjlsd fljfaaklehfa elaksdfaslkdfaekh t</p>
        <p>lkajsdf alsdkj;las l;dsjlsd fljfaaklehfa elaksdfaslkdfaekh t</p>
        <p>lkajsdf alsdkj;las l;dsjlsd fljfaaklehfa elaksdfaslkdfaekh t</p>
        <p>lkajsdf alsdkj;las l;dsjlsd fljfaaklehfa elaksdfaslkdfaekh t</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.appContainer {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

[image]

Heres an example, but with a circle:

[image]

Comment: Yes, You can by adding some padding to your appContainer.

Comment: @AbhishekPatel That just pushes the text down and in but doesn't wrap the text around the border curve.

Answer (score -1):

You can give your app container padding to keep the text inside.

```
.appContainer {
  padding : 10px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: that didnt work: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-mclean-cuijl?file=/src/styles.css